# Invalid port. Exiting... org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError while launching chrome using selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium server standalone jar- 3.11.0, latest ChromeDriver-2.36 and 
 Chrome version 66.0.3359.139

My code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WebDriverBasics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\surya\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver_win32_2\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

But i am unable to launch chrome.its giving below error

```
Invalid port. Exiting...
?? ??, ???? ??:??:?? ????????? org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-5GVJDVR', ip: '192.168.0.104', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at WebDriverBasics.main(WebDriverBasics.java:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:????/status] to be available after ????? ms
    at
```

Comment: Is it you or the system to pad the relevant bits as in `?? ??, ???? ??:??:?? ????????? org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess` and `[http://localhost:????/status] to be available after ????? ms`?

Comment: system..logs in console

Comment: Did you check the solutions given here : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1592

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Invalid port. Exiting...
?? ??, ???? ??:??:?? ????????? org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
```

...implies that the **OsProcess** is unable to bind to the assigned **free port** within your system.

As per the discussion [**`Getting Invalid port error.`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1592) and [**`Invalid port. Exiting...`**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1806)

> **`"Invalid port. Exiting..." occurs when the port assigned to chromedriver is less than 0 or greater than 65535.`**

### Solution

- Execute `netstat` command through *CLI* to see if you have reached limit of possible open connections or check if there is another application running on the given port.
- Check your firewall settings, there is a good chance that firewall configuration may be causing the issue.
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot* to free up the ports.
- Execute your `@Test`.

**Note** : Steps 1, 2, 7 and 8 are vital to debug/solve the issue you are currently facing.

---

### Alternative

As an alternative you can force the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) variant i.e. *ChromeDriver* to start on a specific port e.g. **`65530`** as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(65530).build());
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 65530
  Only local connections are allowed.
  Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
  ChromeDriver was started successfully.
  Jul 20, 2020 7:36:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Invalid port. Exiting..Exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely ChromeDriver Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993623/invalid-port-exiting-exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-webdrivere/62997488#62997488)
- [org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError and org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error with Selenium ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423566/org-openqa-selenium-os-osprocess-checkforerror-and-org-apache-commons-exec-execu/56429042#56429042)
- [“OsProcess checkForError : CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application” while starting Internet Explorer through Java and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621782/osprocess-checkforerror-createprocess-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-appl/51627483#51627483)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the driver location is correct. I am able to launch Facebook without any issue.

```
package Practice;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Facebook 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");


        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");


        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }
}
```

Comment: this not the solution..driver incorrect location doesnot throw this error

Answer (score 0):

change the date from Arabic (or what ever) to English date.

Comment: Please improve your answer by providing some information as to why this change will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you are facing an invalid port exiting error :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Om Sai Ram\\workspace\\com.gmail\\chromedriver.exe" );
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Iran. I also had this error and spent a lot of time for finding it.
But eventually was solved by changing the setting of region in control panel to English.

Answer (score 0):

that working after i use

```
 WebDriver dev= new ChromeDriver(new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(YOUR PORT).build());
```

you can get your port by open WebDriver app
NOTE: keep ChromeDriver running