# Invalid port. Exiting...org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Source code:

package Labarary;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class LAb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("chrome");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Manjit\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Invalid port. Exiting...
??? ??, ???? ??:??:?? ???????

> org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError SEVERE:
> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
> error: 1 (Exit value: 1) Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver
> server to start. Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3',
> time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z' System info: host: 'MANJIT-PC', ip:
> '192.168.1.19', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
> '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_171' Driver info: driver.version:
> ChromeDriver  at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
> at Labarary.LAb.main(LAb.java:20) Caused by:
> org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
> for [http://localhost:?????/status] to be available after ????? ms    at
> org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:187)
> ... 9 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)   at
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:148)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
> ... 10 more

Comment: Do you have any antivirus installed?

Comment: did you check answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245718/invalid-port-exiting-org-openqa-selenium-os-osprocess-checkforerror-while-la

Comment: 1. has webdriver/selenium worked on this machine before or is this you first time
2. if it has worked before, make sure your Chrome.exe hasn't been auto-updated to be incompatible with your driver see [chrome drivers](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
3. the easiest way to fix a port problem is to reset the machine, this clears all ports.
4 goto @mbn217 link shown above

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Invalid port. Exiting... ??? ??, ???? ??:??:?? ???????
org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
```

...implies that the **OsProcess** is unable to bind the *ChromeDriver server process* to the assigned **free port** within your system.

As per the discussion [Getting Invalid port error](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1592) and [Invalid port. Exiting...](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1806)

> **"Invalid port. Exiting..." occurs when the port assigned to chromedriver is less than 0 or greater than 65535.**

### Debugging steps

Perform the following steps to address the core issue:

- Execute `netstat` command through *CLI* to see if you have reached limit of possible open connections or check if there is another application running on the port used by [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871).
- Check your firewall settings, there is a good chance that firewall configuration may be blocking the communication.
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver v2.84](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- Upgrade *Chrome* to  current *Chrome v84.0* levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- Take a *System Reboot* to free up the used ports.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

### Alternative

As an alternative you can force the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) variant i.e. *ChromeDriver* to start on a specific port e.g. **`65535`** as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(65535).build());
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 65535
  Only local connections are allowed.
  Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
  ChromeDriver was started successfully.
  Jul 20, 2020 7:36:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
  ```

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Invalid port. Exiting… org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError while launching chrome using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245718/invalid-port-exiting-org-openqa-selenium-os-osprocess-checkforerror-while-la/50248465#50248465)