# "OsProcess checkForError : CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application" while starting Internet Explorer through Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am working with Selenium Driver in Eclipse (Java), I want to create a driver to test a Internet Explorer page and I keep getting this error message , my driver works fine with firefox and chrome but with explorer I cannot test anything

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\emorales\\Documents\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
//set webdriver to explorer  test
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

//metodo para obtener url
driver.get("http://google.com");

System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

and this is my error stack trace:

```
Jul 31, 2018 1:41:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\emorales\Documents\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'PCPSE0015', ip: '10.1.0.151', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:221)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:150)
    at TEST3.main(TEST3.java:10)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:13816/status] to be available after 20002 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:188)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\emorales\Documents\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)
```

...implies that the *underlying OS* was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsering** session i.e. **Internet Explorer Browser** session.

As per your code trial you are trying to cast the *WebDriver* instance i.e. *driver* to `InternetExplorerDriver()`, so within the line `System.setProperty()` you need to provide the *absolute path* of the respective **IEDriverServer** binary (but not *MicrosoftWebDriver.exe*).

You can download the relevent **IEDriverServer** binary version from the [Index Page](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) and mention in your code as:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\IEDriverServer.exe");
//set webdriver to explorer  test
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

//metodo para obtener url
driver.get("http://google.com");

System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```